# Указать последовательность выполнения функций

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtimer

Впервые засел изучать питон после долгого изучения *C#* и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. (Сразу обозначу что это *PyQt5*)

Есть окно и три кнопки. При нажатии на одну из них необходимо:

- **`заблокировать`** все кнопки;
- воспроизвести звук;
- разблокировать кнопки.

Но на деле получается, что код игнориует последовательность и сначала включает звук, а затем блокирует кнопки (в код разблок специально не добавил).

Как мне реализовать задуманное?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from playsound import playsound
from tkinter import*
from winsound import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(1200, 490)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(255, 78, 238, 255), stop:0.318182 rgba(255, 46, 147, 255), stop:0.727273 rgba(106, 198, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(83, 253, 255, 255));")
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.btn_bool = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_bool.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_bool.setText("")
        self.btn_bool.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.btn_bool.setObjectName("btn_bool")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_bool)
        self.btn_setting = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_setting.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_setting.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../free-icon-setting-8311467.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_setting.setIcon(icon)
        self.btn_setting.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.btn_setting.setObjectName("btn_setting")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_setting)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.btn_help = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_help.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_help.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../button_pomoshh.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_help.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btn_help.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        self.btn_help.setObjectName("btn_help")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_help)
        self.btn_water = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_water.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_water.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../button_voda.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_water.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btn_water.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        self.btn_water.setObjectName("btn_water")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_water)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.add_funcs()


    def lock_btn(self):
        self.btn_setting.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_help.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_water.setEnabled(False)


    def unlock_btn(self):
        self.btn_setting.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_help.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_water.setEnabled(True)

    def play_set(self):
        playsound('set.mp3')

    def add_funcs(self):
        self.btn_setting.clicked.connect(self.settings)
        self.btn_help.clicked.connect(self.help)


    def settings(self):
        self.lock_btn()
        self.play_set()
        #raise SystemExit

    def help(self):
        playsound('help.mp3')
        playsound('help1.mp3')



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Дозатор"))
        MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # скрыть рамку
        MainWindow.showFullScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот конкретное место где нужна помощь:

```
def settings(self):
    self.lock_btn()
    self.play_set()
    #raise SystemExit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.** 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Библиотека **`playsound`** в таком написании:

```
playsound('set.mp3')
```

**блокирует интерфейс**. 
Я закомментировал строки:

```
    MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  
    MainWindow.showFullScreen()
```

чтобы вы убедились в этом. 
Попробуйте переместить окно или изменить разменры окна,
потянув за рамку окна, во время воспроизведения звуков.

Решение проблемы для вашего кода - использование:

**QtCore.[QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html).singleShot(20, self.play_set)**

Я закомментировал ваши стили для тестирования,
чтобы лучше понимать суть происходящего.
Поменяйте изображения и аудио файлы на свои и попробуйте.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from playsound import playsound
# ???from tkinter import *
# ???from winsound import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(800, 490)                               # 1200, 490
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("""
            #MainWindow {                                        /* <--- +++ */
                background-color: qlineargradient(spread:reflect, 
                    x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, 
                    stop:0 rgba(255, 78, 238, 255), 
                    stop:0.318182 rgba(255, 46, 147, 255), 
                    stop:0.727273 rgba(106, 198, 255, 255), 
                    stop:1 rgba(83, 253, 255, 255));
            }
            """)
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.btn_bool = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)

#        self.btn_bool.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_bool.setText("btn_bool")         # + "btn_bool" для тестирования

        self.btn_bool.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.btn_bool.setObjectName("btn_bool")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_bool)
        self.btn_setting = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
#        self.btn_setting.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_setting.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()

#        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../free-icon-setting-8311467.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("boy33.png"), 
            QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        
        self.btn_setting.setIcon(icon)
        self.btn_setting.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 100))
        self.btn_setting.setObjectName("btn_setting")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_setting)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.btn_help = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
#        self.btn_help.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_help.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        
#        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../button_pomoshh.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"), 
            QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        
        self.btn_help.setIcon(icon1)
        self.btn_help.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        self.btn_help.setObjectName("btn_help")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_help)
        self.btn_water = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
#        self.btn_water.setStyleSheet("border : 0;\n"
#     "background: transparent;")
        self.btn_water.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
#        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../button_voda.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"), 
            QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        
        self.btn_water.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btn_water.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 250))
        self.btn_water.setObjectName("btn_water")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_water)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Дозатор"))
        
# !!! Закомментировал для понимания проблемы
#        MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # скрыть рамку
#        MainWindow.showFullScreen()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.add_funcs()

    def lock_btn(self):
        print(f'def lock_btn(self): 111') 
        self.btn_setting.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_help.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_water.setEnabled(False)
        print(f'def lock_btn(self): 222') 

    def unlock_btn(self):
        print(f'def unlock_btn(self): ') 
        self.btn_setting.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_help.setEnabled(True)
        self.btn_water.setEnabled(True)

    def play_set(self):
        print(f'def play_set(self): 111') 
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')                           # set.mp3 
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
        playsound('sounds/login.mp3') 
        playsound('sounds/logout.mp3')
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
        playsound('sounds/shot.wav')
        print(f'def play_set(self): 222') 
        
        self.unlock_btn()                                      # +++

    def add_funcs(self):
        print(f'def add_funcs(self): \n') 
        self.btn_setting.clicked.connect(self.settings)
        self.btn_help.clicked.connect(self.help)

    def settings(self):
        print(f'\ndef settings(self): ') 
        self.lock_btn()
        
#        self.play_set()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(20, self.play_set)           # <---- !!!
        
        #raise SystemExit

    def help(self): 
        print(f'def help(self): \n') #
        playsound('sounds/login.mp3')                           # help.mp3
        playsound('sounds/logout.mp3')                          # help1.mp3
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @СергейКачалов что не так?

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ, весьма полезно и познавательно, один только вопрос, программа пробивает даже через заблокированную кнопку. т.е. вот я нажимаю верхнюю кнопку, воспроизводится звук, а если нажать на левую заблокированную кнопку, то после разблокировки срабатывает звук и оттуда. Это решаемо?

Comment: @СергейКачалов пожалуйста, я думаю что все решаемо. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приложите ваш код и хорошо расскажите, что вы хотите сделать, и что у вас не получается.